# Application finished with exit code 134

Tags: qt

I have a qt program. It has some classes and after I defined a global variable of a class that inherited from `QWidget`, deploy became unsuccessful. what should I do?
The error is as shown below.

> QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QWidget
>   bash: line 1:  2230 Aborted                 DISPLAY=':0.0' /program-path
>   Application finished with exit code 134.

Comment: it would be helpful if you could provide your source code. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

As it is seen from the error message:

> Must construct a QApplication before a QWidget

Your global inherited from `QWidget` is constructed before the `main` function.

It is a bad idea to have such global.

However if you really want to have fun with that you can try some kind of singleton or at least put that static variable into getter function to make sure that the object is instantiated only during the first access. You should also be sure that the first access is after `QApplication` instantiation in `main()`. The classic Qt Widget Application template may look like this:

```
MainWindow& getGlobalMainWindow()
{
    static MainWindow w;
    return w;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    getGlobalMainWindow().show();
    //...
}
```

However it is indeed a bad idea. In the above example `MainWindow` (and its child widgets) is destroyed after `QApplication`. If some of those destructors relies on `QApplication` it will be a problem.

So, the best solution is to avoid global `QWidget` objects.